# LED filament bulbs without an envelope?

Tags: led

Is it possible to remove the envelope from an LED "filament" bulb and still have it work? Are they in an atmosphere?

Comment: Sounds like a relatively inexpensive experiment to try at home.

Comment: No atmosphere, but the outer envelope do provide the isolation barrier between the mains and you.

Comment: Yes. They are not sealed. Beware of the high voltage.

Comment: It is possible. I've used them as hands on an analog clock, for example. I've done it as a quicker and more certain alternative to buying the filaments from China.

Comment: Maybe @winny can write that up as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

There is no special atmosphere inside LED bulbs, some even have ventilation holes. The purpose of the outer envelope is to isolate the user from the mains voltage present on most LED bulbs and to make them mechanically compatible with normal A65 or similar incandescent bulbs.

So, yes it would still work without the envelope but no, you can not remove it due to the electrocution hazard.

Comment: The outer envelope also usually functions as a diffuser.